# INSERTAR INPUT FILE EN MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes estoy realizando un formulario que con java agregue o elimine dos input file, el problema es que cuando quiero que estos se envien y la ruta se inserte en una tabla de mysql, no me toma el valor del segundo input, solo el primero.

este es el fragmento del html para el envio de los archivos

```
<div class="card shadow mb-4">
<div class="card-header py-3 card" style="background-color: #17325c;">
<h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-white"> <i class="fas fa-file"></i> Enviar Tarea</h6>
</div>
<div class="card-body">
       <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">
       <tr>
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
  <td><input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" /></td>
     
  </div>
  <div class="input-group-append">

  <td style="width:15px;"><button name="add" id="add" class="btn text-white" style="background-color: #17325c;" type="button">+</button></td>
  
  </div>
 </div></tr>
 </table>  
 
    <div align="right">
            
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn text-white"style="background-color: #17325c;"></div>
</form>
```

el script para agregar y eliminar  el input, no permite agregar mas de 2

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#fuSubirExcel").on('change', function() {
    var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
    $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);        
})

});

$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;
    $('#add').click(function(){
        i++;
    if (i>=3){

alert("NO PUEDES AGREGAR MAS"); }
  
 if (i==2){
        $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="file" name="jon" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');
    }
  });
$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){
        var button_id = $(this).attr("id"); 
        $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

el php con el que se cargan los archivos y donde no me lee el segundo input, me lo marca como desconocido

```
<?php
$archivo=$ncuenta.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$archivo1=$ncuenta.basename($_FILES['jon']['name']);
$directorio = 'NUEVO/';
$subir_archivo = $directorio.$ncuenta.basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$subir_archivo1 = $directorio.$ncuenta.basename($_FILES['file2']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $subir_archivo) || (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file2']['tmp_name'], $subir_archivo1))) {
  
$sql="INSERT INTO tareasenviadas (ncuenta,nombre,fecha,grupo,profesor,titulo,materia,comentarios,archivo,archivo1) VALUES ('$ncuenta','$nombre','$fecha','$grupo','$profesor','$titulo','$materia','$reporte','$archivo','$archivo1')";
   
$db = obtenerConexion();
$rs=ejecutarQuery($db, $sql);
?>
```

espero me puedan ayudar, ya que he intentado concatenar el name del segundo input pero ni asi me lo detecta.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Dicho esto, creo que no usas Java en ninguna parte de tu código. He visto javascript y PHP, pero no Java. Además, tu código podría sufrir los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL) debido a la forma en la que concatenas el contenido de variables al código SQL.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar las bibliotecas javascript y CSS que usas en tu código para facilitar que reproduzcamos tu problema? Según intuyo, al menos usas jQuery y Bootstrap. ¿Podrías confirmarnos qué versiones usas? Si compartes el código de `ejecutarQuery` podremos ayudarte a corregir la inyección SQL.

Comment: DE HECHO SI ES JAVASCRIPT SOLO QUE NO AGREGUE COMPLETO EL NOMBRE

Comment: ```<?php
    function obtenerConexion() {  $db = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'platafo1_cobaem');  $db->set_charset("utf8"); if($db->connect_errno > 0){ die('Error de conexion a bd [' . $db->connect_error . ']'); }
        return $db; 
    }
     }
    function ejecutarQuery($db, $sql) {
        if(!$resultado = $db->query($sql)){
            die('No se puede ejecutar el query [' . $db->error . ']'.$sql);
        }
        return $resultado;
    } ```

Comment: Por favor, agrega ese código a tu pregunta editándola, gracias. PD: por favor, no escribas todo el texto en mayúsculas. Escribir en mayúsculas equivale a gritar y está mal visto.

Answer (score 3):

Si tu primer `input` tiene `name="file"` y tu segundo input (que insertas con `jQuery` tiene `name="jon"` entonces en el `php` deberías referirte siempre a él con `$_FILES['jon']` pero veo que en `$subir_archivo1` y en `move_uploaded_file` estás usando `$_FILES['files2']`.

También podrías usar un `array` en el nombre: `name="files[]"` y luego procesar cada dato con un `foreach` o similar en php.

Dicho lo anterior también considera revisar la implementación de tus consultas para evitar problemas de seguridad. Te sugiero averiguar algo sobre [pdo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php) para empezar.

Comment: DE HECHO SI CAMBIE ESE NOMBRE POR QUE PROBE UN SEGUNDO NOMBRE, EL DETALLE QUE NO ME LO RECONOCE AHORA SI LO AGREGO CON EL ARRAY COMO AGREGARIA LA CONSULTA DE MYSQL PARA QUE SE INSERTE EN UN SOLO REGISTRO?

Comment: En ese caso sería más práctico guardar un registro con los detalles de cada archivo enviado, o guardar una lista de archivos en una sola columna, en algun formato como json que permita despues descomponerlo en una lista de archivos.